# Snapshot of the mirrored database fails due to log issue

Tags: sql, snapshot, mirroring

We have server A hosting principal database and server B hosting its mirror. To minimize the workload caused by reporting we are creating daily snapshot of the mirror database on Server B. For years we were running the same job and it was working fine.

The code we use first deletes the old snapshot (this still works) and then creates the brand new one using the query:

```
create database [DB_snapshot] on 
   (name = N'rsdev3',filename = N'd:\snapshot\DB.sqlsnapshot' ) ,
   (name = N'indexes',filename = N'd:\snapshot\DB_indexes.sqlsnapshot' ) 
as snapshot of DB
```

The above code worked fine so far, but today for the first time we got the following error:

Error message

> Msg 1823, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 
>   A database snapshot cannot be
>   created because it failed to start. 
>   Msg 1823, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   A database snapshot cannot be created because it failed to start.
>   Msg 3456, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 
>   Could not redo log record (202011:19306:2), for transaction ID (0:0), on page (1:1823948),
>   allocation unit 281474979397632, database 'DB_snapshot' (database ID
>   6). Page: LSN = (201954:220201:1), allocation unit = 281474979397632,
>   type = 1. Log: OpCode = 4, context 18, PrevPageLSN: (202010:23679:1).
>   Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database. Msg
>   3313, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 During redoing of a logged operation
>   in database 'DB_snapshot', an error occurred at log record ID
>   (202011:19306:2). Typically, the specific failure is previously logged
>   as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database
>   from a full backup, or repair the database.

I goggled it, but nothing helpful came up. I am afraid that I may end up disconnecting and then connecting again the mirroring, but I would prefer to avoid doing it because it would be very inconvenient right now.

Have you ever experience something similar? Do you have any ideas how to fix this? I will be very grateful for any tips and advices!

Comment: Run CHECKDB and post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any of you are wondering what caused this rather unusual problem please read ahead.

After a few hours of monitoring we found a culprit. It turned out that the server on which the database is mirrored was used more heavily that day. As a consequence new transactions on principal were created faster than the mirroring could transfer them to the mirror server. As soon as the workload decreased, principal to mirror transfer speed increased significantly. Outstanding transaction were copied and in a few hours everything was back to normal.